# Button inside UITableCell - passing data to selector

Tags: ios, uitableview, selector

This subject is all over the stackoverflow but I couldn't find a fitting solution.

I have button on each `UITableViewCell`.

Here is how I create the cell.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExaminationCell"];
    UIButton *clipButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    MedicalExamination *examination = [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [clipButton addTarget:self action:@selector(examinatonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

Here is the method thah should handle the button click:

```
-(void)examinatonClicked:(MedicalExamination*)examination
{

}
```

How do I pass examination object to `examinatonCommentsClicked` method? Obviously the object is different for each cell...

Comment: You can use the solution provided in this answer regarding UIButton and passing mulitple parameters to its selector: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779104/5324541

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you have to add button in `uitableviewCell` through `xib(custum cell)` and then connect it through `iboutlet`.

Comment: Well, Dheerendra is kinda right, is achievable this way... however I dont think xib is necessary, just custom UITableVIewClass

Comment: is it possible to pass examination through NSsstring which is globle Object?

Comment: or create custom uitableviewcell with a new property called examination. thats all, not xibs.

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat hacky thing that I'll do, is I'll use the UIButton's tag attribute to pass the row number so I can pull the object from the array that's backing my table.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExaminationCell"];
    UIButton *clipButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    clipButton.tag = indexPath.row //Set the UIButton's tag to the row.

    MedicalExamination *examination = [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [clipButton addTarget:self action:@selector(examinatonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

-(void)examinatonClicked: (id)sender
{
     int row = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
     MedicalExamination *examination = [objects objectAtIndex: row];
     //Profit!
}
```